# Why are my photos not restored completely from a computer backup?

Tags: iphone, ios, backup, photos, restore

I downgraded my Iphone and after downgrading, I restored my backup downloaded in the Mac but not all of my photos are restored. I dont want to download my pictures from Icloud because it will not be chronologically arranged. I hope someone will help

Comment: How are the pictures arranged in icloud? How does it differ they seem the same to me across devices

Comment: iCloud should indeed maintain the date stamp on the pictures, along with any other metadata set in the pictures. What makes you think your photos will *not* be chronologically arranged any more?

Comment: when i downloaded the zip file, the pictures are shuffled and i only used documents by readdle to transfer it to the photo library